# Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugGoogleServices’ looking for google-services.json and unsuccessfully finding it

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I just installed the cordova firebase analytics plugin from (https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics) but there seems to be a problem finding the google-services.json file.

This file is in the root of the Ionic project and has not caused me any trouble up until now. I have been using the cordova-plugin-firebase and angular fire 2 plugin with no trouble beforehand.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugGoogleServices’.
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User1\WebstormProjects\IONIC\Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

I assume you added your `google-services.json` services to your project's root.

In the platform tag for Android add the following resource-file tag if you are using **cordova-android 7.0 or greater**:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

If you are using **cordova-android 6.x or earlier**, add the following resource-file tag:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

Also make sure that dependent plugins, specially **cordova-support-google-services**, is installed with latest version 1.2.0.

As a side note, those Firebase plugins from **chemerisuk** tend to have these type of Cordova errors and warnings, which are a pain to fix. I've been dealing with his Firebase Auth plugin which shows identical errors, the funny thing is that plugin and app work just fine anyway.